# BS4: Attribute Error in Web Scraping with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

I need to extract from this website [link](https://www.biedronka.pl/pl/sklepy/lista,lat,52.25,lng,21,page,) name of the city where shops are located. I created this code:

```
def get_page_data(number):
    print('number:', number)

    url = 'https://www.biedronka.pl/pl/sklepy/lista,lat,52.25,lng,21,page,'.format(number)
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    container = soup.find(class_='s-content shop-list-page')
    items = container.find_all(class_='shopListElement')

    dane = []
    for item in items:
        miasto = item.find(class_='h4').get_text(strip=True)
        adres = item.find(class_='shopFullAddress').get_text(strip=True)
        dane.append([adres])

    return dane

wszystkie_dane = []
for number in range(1, 2):
    dane_na_stronie = get_page_data(number)

    wszystkie_dane.extend(dane_na_stronie)

dane = pd.DataFrame(wszystkie_dane, columns=['miasto','adres'])

dane.to_csv('biedronki_lista.csv', index=False)
```

The problem appears in:

```
   miasto = item.find(class_='h4').get_text(strip=True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Any ideas how to extract name of the city (in h4) from this website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
miasto = item.find('h4').text.split()[0]
```

Or:

```
miasto = item.find('h4').get_text(strip=True)
```

Note:

> "h4" is a tag, not a class.

---

Explanation:

- When you give .find('h4'), it returns:

```
<h4 style="margin-bottom: 10px;">

                Rzeszów             <span class="shopFullAddress">ul.<span class="shopAddress"> </span></span>
```

- When you give `.text`, it returns:

```
'Rzeszów            \tul.'
```

- When you give .split(), it returns:

```
['Rzeszów', 'ul.']
```

- And from this we take what we require.

So do this where-ever you face error in this code.

```
dane = []
    for item in items:
        miasto = item.find('h4').get_text(strip=True)
        adres = item.find('shopFullAddress').get_text(strip=True)
        dane.append([adres])
```

Comment: remove the `class_=`

Comment: `shopFullAddress` is not a class

Answer (score 3):

`class_='h4'` is an attribute you are passing a tag name to the class which is not correct instead :

```
miasto = item.find('h4').get_text(strip=True)
```